# Argument of \genfrac has an extra }

Tags: fractions

Can't figure out what is wrong with the syntax below, for which I get the error mentioned in the title:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$k = \frac{\omega M}{2 \big\lbrack \left( L_SL_D \right) ^\frac{1}{2} \big\rbrack}$

\end{document}
```

The error reported is

```
! Argument of \genfrac  has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.161 ... L_SL_D \right) ^\frac{1}{2} \big\rbrack}
                                                  $ \\
?
```

Please let me know how I could fix this.

TIA

Comment: It must be somewhere else. I don't get any error.

Comment: is there an easy way to locate this stray }? As I write this, I am doing a grep for '}'.

Comment: Have you tried encasing `\frac{1}{2}` in an extra pair of curly braces, i.e., writing `...\right) ^{\frac{1}{2}} ...`? Maybe that'll cause the error message to pop up somewhere else.

Comment: I have used \left( and \right) combination with fractions....I will look for that now...I just completed a grep for a stray '}' of the whole file, and there is none...

Comment: the weird thing is that the line number where it is cribbing used to compile without any problem previously....so I am suspecting it is the text that I added of late that is the cause.....I tried commenting out a large chunk of recently added text so that I could confirm this....but somehow the error still persisted.....one lesson learnt from this is to keep a backup of the last working file just in case something like this creeps up...

Comment: Do you continue to get an error if you drop the redundant square brackets and the `\left` and `\right` sizing directives and write `$k = \frac{\omega M}{2  ( L_SL_D ) ^{0.5} }$`?

Comment: I just commented out that particular line and now it showed me a syntax error in the table where I had missed out a \\ before an \hline and I fixed it...but I now get something like ! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 437.
<inserted text>
                \fi
I am about search for this now...but strangely, there is no \iffalse anywhere in my document

Comment: this is something totally unrelated to the syntax in the file I guess...I just copied a backed up file last night which was compiling without any problem and now I see the same error for that file as well......I am going to restart the machine and see if that helps.....just in case

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an error not related to the material that was posted.

Comment: If removing new material does not work, try deleting all files generated by TeX (.aux, etc.).

Comment: couldn't figure out what caused the error....but was able to get back to status quo ante after switching to a different working directory reproduced from backup and abandoning the directory where problems were reported.....not proceeding with further debugging as of now due to time constraints...